# C++ Stair Climber Recursion Issue?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

The goal is to write a program that computes and prints all of the different ways a person can climb n-stairs by taking 1, 2, or 3 stairs at at time.

I'm having a slight issue with my recursive algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;ctor< vector<int> > outer;
vector<int> inner;

vector< vector<int> > get_ways(int num_stairs) {
    // TODO: Return a vector of vectors of ints representing
    // the different combinations of ways to climb num_stairs
    // stairs, moving up either 1, 2, or 3 stairs at a time.
    if (num_stairs <= 0) {
        outer.push_back(inner);
        inner.clear();
    }
    if (num_stairs >= 1) {
        inner.push_back(1);
        get_ways(num_stairs-1);
    }
    if (num_stairs >= 2) {
        inner.push_back(2);
        get_ways(num_stairs-2);
    }
    if (num_stairs >= 3) {
        inner.push_back(3);
        get_ways(num_stairs-3);
    }

    return outer;
}

void display_ways(const vector< vector<int> > &ways) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ways.size(); i++) {
        cout << i+1 << ". " << "[";
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < ways[i].size(); j++) {
            if (j != ways[i].size()-1)
                cout << ways[i][j] << ", ";
            else
                cout << ways[i][j];
        }
        cout << "]" << endl;
    }
}
```

Example of error:

**get_ways(3)**

**Expected output ->**

1. [1, 1, 1]
2. [1, 2]
3. [2, 1]
4. [3]

**Actual output ->**

1. [1, 1, 1]

//algorithm doesn't print preceding 1s if recursion hits multiple if statements?

**2. [2]**

3. [2, 1]
4. [3]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make your actual output clear (you can  look at the preview of your question to see what others see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual code should be:

```
vector< vector<int> > get_ways(int num_stairs) {
    if (num_stairs <= 0) {
        outer.push_back(inner);
    }
    if (num_stairs >= 1) {
        inner.push_back(1);
        get_ways(num_stairs-1);
        inner.pop_back();
    }
    if (num_stairs >= 2) {
        inner.push_back(2);
        get_ways(num_stairs-2);
        inner.pop_back();
    }
    if (num_stairs >= 3) {
        inner.push_back(3);
        get_ways(num_stairs-3);
        inner.pop_back();
    }

    return outer;
}
```

Why your code is incorrect? Let's trace the function stack and the vector `inner`:

```
Function stack              inner
get_way(3)                  []
  get_way(2)                [1]
    get_ways(1)             [1,1]
      get_ways(0)           [1,1,1] (*)
    get_ways(0)             [2]
    ....
```

At point (*) you clear `inner` and at the next step of the `get_ways(2)` execution you would have the vector  `[2]` instead of `[1, 2]`. So instead of clearing `inner`, after finishing a recursive call, you should pop the element you've pushed last in `inner`. This is a common rule you should always keep while backtracking - always bring the object back to the state it had been before the recursion call.

Comment: No need to reply, but if you have a few minutes, I have one more quick question. My program works, but seems to be running extremely slow when running with n > 15, to the point where it doesn't even output anything, and just freezes. Is this just the nature of the recursive algorithm? Is there anyway to optimize the algorithm easily? If you don't have time to reply, no worries! Thanks again!

Comment: @mark The number of the combinations grows exponentially. That means that the is no algorithm that would enumerate all combinations effectively. However, you can find the count of the combinations in linear time (without enumerating them) using memoization.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thanks again!